# Why does my form in Rails not set my attribute when I create a new instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters, attributes

I am trying to follow the [Jumpstart Labs Rails-Blogger Tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i2:-adding-comments) and I am trying to add comments to the articles that are created.

Here is my code for when I `create` a comment:

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.create!(comment_params)
    flash.notice = "Your comment was created successfully!"

    redirect_to article_path(@comment.article_id)
end

def comment_params
    article_id = params[:article_id]
    params.require(:comment).permit(:author_name, :body)
end
```

When I am on the article page, and I try to submit my comment through my comment form, I get this error:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

I realize that it can not find the `article_id` associated with my comment, but I can't find my error. It is clearly not setting the `article_id` attribute correctly inside my `comment_params` method, and my question is why is it giving the `article_id` a nil value?

Please note that I have also tried doing:

`@comment.article_id = params[:article_id]`
`:article_id = params[:article_id]`

and neither of these work. I've tried putting `article_id` as a symbol in multiple ways, but It still gives it a nil value.

---

**Edit:**

I thought it might be useful to include this. Here is what the tutorial says to do:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.article_id = params[:article_id]

  @comment.save

  redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
end

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:author_name, :body)
end
```

However, I want to use the `.create` method instead, that way it only uses one line. My problem is when I try to set the comment's `article_id`. That is where it fails, and I don't know how to set the `article_id` using the `.create` method, considering that it saves the comment automatically.

---

**SECOND EDIT**

Here is the form used to create my comments:

```
<h3>Post a Comment</h3>

<%= form_for [ @article, @comment ] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :author_name, "Your name" %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :author_name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :body, "Your comment" %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

---

**THIRD EDIT**

Here is a picture of my error. Notice at the bottom that it has a hash with the correct article_id, however it assigns the article_id with a nil value.

[image: Local Host Error]

Comment: Nothing in `comment_params` sets an article_id anywhere useful,  just a local that is then thrown away. I don't see anything that associates your comment with an article, although in fairness I have no idea what context you tried the `@comment.article_id` in.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `article_id` is nil.

First, your `comment_params` method should be like this:

```
def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:author_name, :body, :article_id)
end
```

If you don't permit `:article_id`, it'll get filtered out and be set to nil. I suspect that's what's happening.

If that doesn't work, make sure that you're actually passing the `article_id` in the params (check your server logs). I imagine it's in a hidden field or button params maybe?

Comment: Adding it to `.permit` didn't help. It actually seems to be that i'm incorrectly calling `article_id` on `@comment` inside the `create` method when I got to redirect. When I go to submit a comment, it says that the agrgument for redirecting to the article is nil (the article id), but at the very bottom of the localhost page, it has a hash with all the parameters for that comment, and it contains the correct article_id, so it must be the way i'm calling the article_id in the redirect statement. Although, I'm not sure why it's not getting the article_id of the `@comment`.

Comment: Nevermind.. Ok, so on the localhost error page, it shows the correct article_id associated with that comment at the very bottom inside a hash. However, when I go to `rails console` inside my rails app, and call `Comment.all`, it shows that the comments have a `nil` value for the `article_id`. I have no idea as to why this is.

Comment: Please post your form or button or whatever you use to create comments.

Answer (score 0):

Either add

```
@comment.article_id = params[:comment][:article_id]
```

---

OR just add `article_id` to your permitted params:

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:author_name, :body, :article_id)
```

---

And make sure it is sent correctly from the view.